# cannot open downloaded file having '&' symbol in filename

Tags: php, file, download

I want to download files uploaded to the server.I have the filenames as  links and I need to download the file directly when the user click it.I have succeeded in that.The issue now I face is I cant open the files containing `amp` symbols in their filename,eventhough it is downloaded. eg: &,test.doc(filename containing other special symbols can be downloaded and opened properly.)

My php script is like this:

```
<script>
function downloadme(file){          
    var link = "download.php?file=" + file; 
    location.replace(link);
} 
</script>

<a title="Click to download" href="javascript:downloadme()">filename</a>
```

download.php

```
<?php
$path = $_GET['file'];
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($path . $uri[1]) . "\"" ); 
@readfile($path);  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I did

download.php:

```
<?php
$path = $_GET['file'];
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($path . $uri[1]) . "\"" ); 
@readfile($_GET['file']);
?>
```

html file:

```
<script>
function downloadme(file){          
    var link = "download.php?file=" + escape(file);
    location.replace(link);
} 
</script>

<a title="Click to download" href="javascript:downloadme('test&12.doc')">filename</a>
```

Comment: Encode the file in javascript
`var link = "download.php?file=" + encodeURI(file);`
then decode in PHP

Comment: file is downloaded with the file name(if eg:filename has the filename as test&12.doc)as 'test' only.That means characters after & is not recieved.So the filename is unable to open

Comment: Edited my answer. Check if it works for you. Cheers!